# Objective C - create NSDate from two Strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

Short version: Is there a way to combine two `NSDates` (which can be formed from two different strings) into a single `NSDate` object?

Detail: In my app, there are two textfields where the user enters the day and the time, respectively (these are entered using a customised Date Picker). When I want to save the information in the database, the property of the object expects a single date, comprised of both the day and the time.

Here is how I set the strings:

```
 if ([mode isEqualToString:@"date"])
{
    self.dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [self.dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];
    self.dateTextField.text = [self.dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
}
else if ([mode isEqualToString:@"time"])
{
    self.timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [self.timeFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    self.timeTextField.text = [self.timeFormat stringFromDate:date];
}
```

where `date` is a `NSDate` passed in to the method. Now when I am trying to save the information  in a different method, I have access to the strings and the date formats, so I am able to do

```
NSDate* tempDate = [self.dateFormat dateFromString: self.dateTextField.text];
NSDate* tempTime = [self.timeFormat dateFromString: self.timeTextField.text];
```

but that's as far as I can get... I'm not sure how to combine the dates together into a single entity. Would I combine the DateFormatter strings together somehow?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: you could try concatenating the 2 dates together as such NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tempDate + tempTime"]; try that out

Comment: If you have only a time, what date is assumed?  If you have both, combine them before creating the new NSDate object.

Comment: @HotLicks With just a time, the date assumed is today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
NSString *strTemp = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"%@ %@",self.dateTextField.text,self.timeTextField.text];

NSDateFormatter *dateFotmatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[self.dateFotmatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy hh:mm a"];

NSDate* tempDate = [self.dateFotmatter dateFromString:strTemp];
```

Hope it helps.

Enjoy coding.