# Formatting a date from string returns NULL

Tags: ios, date, nsdateformatter

I have two different strings, one for the date and the other one for the time.
I have combined the two and I want to get an NSDate from it.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *format = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"yyyy-MM-dd" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[formatter setDateFormat:format];
NSString *date = [formatter stringFromDate:temp];
NSLog(@"%@",date); //This shows 10/11/2013
NSDateFormatter *formatterTime = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSString *formatTime = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"j:mm" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[formatterTime setDateFormat:formatTime];
NSDate *tTime = [formatterTime dateFromString:[self.arrayOrari objectAtIndex:a]];
NSString *time = [formatterTime stringFromDate:tTime];
NSLog(@"%@",time); //This shows 6:58 PM

NSString *dateTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",date,time];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *formatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"yyyy-MM-dd j:mm" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatString];
myMed.orario = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTime];
NSLog(@"%@",myMed.orario); //This shows NULL
```

I've been trying since about four hours, but I'm not able to solve this problem.
Any idea?

UPDATE:
I've tried this, as suggested:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *format = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"yyyy-MM-dd" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[formatter setDateFormat:format];
NSString *date = [formatter stringFromDate:temp];
NSLog(@"%@",date); //This shows 10/11/2013
NSDateFormatter *formatterTime = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSString *formatTime = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"HH:mm" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[formatterTime setDateFormat:formatTime];
NSDate *tTime = [formatterTime dateFromString:[self.arrayOrari objectAtIndex:a]];
NSString *time = [formatterTime stringFromDate:tTime];
NSLog(@"%@",time); //This shows 18:58

NSString *dateTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",date,time];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *formatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatString];
myMed.orario = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTime];
NSLog(@"%@",myMed.orario); //This shows NULL
```

Comment: See this question from earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321964/objective-c-create-nsdate-from-two-strings

Comment: Do not use `j` for the hour. Use `HH` or `hh` depending on whether your want 24 or 12-hour formatting. See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Please search for some prior questions about date formatting.  Questions like this get asked daily (often 2-3 times) and it gets tiresome.  (Which makes us even crankier.)

Comment: @rmaddy I've seen your link and tried using HH or hh, the result is always null.

Comment: Without seeing your updated code it's hard to help.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm sorry to bother, but I really believe I've seen all similar questions on SO before posting mine. Nothing seems to work...

Comment: What have you done to debug it?  Have you checked the generated format strings to be sure they match the actual format of the data?  At least break it down to one thing that doesn't work (and everything up to that point did) vs saying "it doesn't work" for a whole blob of code.

Comment: Are you sure `myMed` itself is not nil?

Comment: @HotLicks have you seen the comments in the code? The formatted date show as "10/11/2013", even if the formatter is set to "yyyy-MM-dd". The formatted time shows as "18:58" if I use "HH:mm". The resulting string, the one I want to convert back to a NSDate, is "10/11/2003 18:58".

Comment: @AnnaKarenina I'm sure. Anyway I've tried to log directly "[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTime]" with the same result.

Comment: Have you printed out the format strings?  You claim your problem is converting from string to NSDate, and if the format string does not match the actual date string then obviously it will fail.  (Normally one doesn't use dateFormatFromTemplate for string->NSDate conversion.)

Comment: Get it down to a single failing statement, listing the inputs (date format and date string) and the output (if any).  Show us that.  Don't show us 15-20 lines of code and say "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally did it!

The final formatting string had to be: "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm". I did try to use "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm" but it didn't work, I had to use the exact separators.

Comment: We kept asking you to show us the actual format strings and date strings.

Comment: In the code I've shown you can see the format strings I was using and the console logs. You all were right about using HH instead of j, but I should also have used the separator / instead of -

Comment: You did not show us a credible copy of both the format string (not the input to dateFormaFromTemplate, but its output) and the input date string.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is over here:

```
NSString *formatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"yyyy-MM-dd j:mm" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

instead of

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd j:mm"
```

try:

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"
```

Comment: I've tried with both hh and HH but the result is always null.